# Iphone:APNS without Alert in the message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, alert, apple-push-notifications

If the message is sent without alert from server,Is there any way to process that message When App is running in Foreground??

Answer (score 0):

When your app is running all notifications are send to the app delegate:

`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo`

Comment: which types are you registering with `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:`

Comment: NSDictionary *apsDic = [userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"];
    NSString *alertStr = [apsDic valueForKey:@"alert"];
    NSLog(@"alertstring =%@",alertStr);
    NSString *msgStr = [userInfo valueForKey:@"m"];
    NSLog(@"messtring= %@",msgStr);
    NSNumber *badgeNum = [apsDic valueForKey:@"badge"];
    NSLog(@"Badge Number = %@",badgeNum); i am writing this piece of code

Comment: that was not my question .. what types are you registering with the `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` call when you start your app?

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert ];

Comment: hmm..then it should work if you include alert or badge information